# Is it possible to secure Cloud front distribution to be accessed only within VPC or ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-vpc

I want to read an S3 through Cloud front.  I have made S3 as private and I want to secure cloud front distribution url as well.  Is it possible to make Cloud front accessible only with in VPC or ECS?

Thanks.

Comment: This does not look like a programming question.

Comment: Why CloudFront if you can simply use VPC endpoint and restrict S3 from VPC endpoint ? It'll work if they're in the same region and latency will be low as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach [WAF(Web Applicaton Firewall)](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to secure the cloudfront distribution. You can utilise [IP Match Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-ip-conditions.html) in the WAF to allow the traffic only from a set of IPs

> If you want to allow or block web requests based on the IP addresses
>   that the requests originate from, create one or more IP match
>   conditions. An IP match condition lists up to 10,000 IP addresses or
>   IP address ranges that your requests originate from. Later in the
>   process, when you create a web ACL, you specify whether to allow or
>   block requests from those IP addresses.